# Linq to SQL table inheritance in ASP.net Dynamic Data

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, dynamic-data

I have a Linq to SQL data model that uses single table inheritance.

I created a new ASP.net Dynamic Data web site with all table scaffolding enabled, but I can't see any of the derived classes in my data model being scaffolded.

Is this by design?

Answer (score 0):

Table Inheritance is possible with (unreleased) ASP.NET 4.0 using LINQ to SQL.  The Dynamic Data Samples / Futures download-able [here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/27026) have an Inheritance.dbml file that the team created specifically to demonstrate this.

Also see the [Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd793152%28VS.100%29.aspx), which applies to Entity Framework.